# What does the number pair mean in the output of NSException?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsexception

Sorry, I'm afraid this question is fairly ambiguous but I don't know the correct terminology to use. Maybe someone could edit it?

I'm trying to fathom what this problem is

```
2012-12-23 09:53:36.827 myApp[10768:303] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 13 beyond bounds for empty array
```

does the number pair in squard brackets refer to a line number or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [processId:logging thread's Mach port]

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any ideas how I could track down this error?

Comment: It says that you're trying to access 13th element in array while it has less that 13 elements total. If you want to find where this error is you can track stack trace which has to be opened at the left of XCode when you run your app and it crashes.

Comment: Ahh great, I've found the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Depends on what you mean by “your array has no value”. There is definitely an array, but it contains no objects.